# OSM vector map error while installing osm localization extention

Tags: openstreetmap

When setting up vector OSM map extension and used this command,
sudo apt-get -y install ./postgresql-*-osml10n_*_amd64.deb,
I got following error
E: Unsupported file ../postgresql*osmll0n*amd64.deb given on commandline

Please help to resolve this error

Comment: If you want to install a local `.deb` then you have to use `dpkg` instead of `apt`.
Offtopic, not a programming-related problem.